# Hook To Get All Posts Deleted

Tags: posts, actions, customization

I've added an which makes a call to an external service every time a post is deleted. However, it's on the `delete_post` hook, which works fine when I delete a single post, but if multiple posts are deleted at once, then it makes a call for every post, which is timing out.

Is there a hook or a way of accessing all the deleted posts when they're being deleted, rather than one at a time?

Comment: What interface are you using to delete multiple posts (is it the standard WP backend or something custom)? More importantly, how is the list of posts to delete being passed to PHP/WP (query parameter, post, ajax, etc)?

Comment: Standard WP Admin UI, clicking the buttons and all that to trash, say, 5 posts or whathaveyou. The plugin exports posts, so it's just acting on regular posts through normal WordPress means.